# self.value versus self

Tags: python, oop

what is difference of between self.value and just self while using inside **add** and **radd** class methods. its throwing me a type error when i am using self.value inside **radd** but it just works fine in **add** method how is that different

```
class Numstring:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = str(value)

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return int(self) + other

 #  def __add__(self, other):
 #      return int(self.vaue) + other**

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other

 #  def __radd__(self, other):
 #      return self.vaue + other 

foo = Numstring(5)

# working when using both self.value and self
add = foo + 4  

#not working when using self.value in __radd__ (but
#working when using only self what is the difference)
add2 = 4 + foo 

print(add)
print(add2)
```

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect ``self.value + other`` to work? ``self.value`` is a string. Can you clarify why you expect ``self`` and ``self.value`` to be exchangeable? They are not the same type. Also note that ``__add__`` uses ``int(self)``/``int(self.value)``, whereas in ``__radd__`` a bare ``self``/``self.value`` is used.

Comment: Please refrain from adding markdown into code samples. The markdown bold indicator ``**`` is not interpreted inside code, but requires to be manually removed before being able to run your code samples.

Comment: removed mark down sorry for the inconvenience caused

Answer (score 0):

If you use `self + other` then it invokes `self.__add__(other)` where you use `int(self.value) + other` which seems correct since `self.value` is of type `str`. However if in `__radd__` you use `self.value + other` then you attempt to add `str` and `int` which gives a `TypeError`. If you used also `int(self.value) + other` then it would work. Note that you can leave out the definition of `__radd__` if it is similar to `__add__` as it will fallback on it (if the l.h.s. operand doesn't support it).

Comment: it works when i do int(self.value)  inside __radd__ because addition between two its is being performed
but when i just use self it works even though i am not casting it 

def __radd__(self, other):
   return self + other

Comment: @VarunKashyap I have explained that in my answer, `self + other` invokes `self.__add__(other)` and there you cast to `int`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems there's some typo error in you example like `self.vaue` rather than `self.value`

self will adress the class instance, self.value will adress the class property you defined.

Comment: The problem description mentions that a TypeError is thrown. Mistyping an attribute name would raise an AttributeError. The commented code shown is not the code the OP inquires about.

Comment: Guessed Varun tries where somehow also related to the typo error and so that he'd like to sort this out and uncomment or remove commented lines for us to answer more precisely. Whatever, thx for having replied.